# How to construct a bump function where one plateau is not at zero?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a linear function with $f(x_0)=0$, $f(\epsilon)=1$, where $\varepsilon >0$ fulfills $x_0-\varepsilon > \varepsilon>0$. I am trying to construct a smooth function $\psi:  \mathbb{R} \to [0,1]$, which fullfills $\psi(x)=\begin{cases} 1, \text{ for } x \le \varepsilon - r_0 \\ f(x), \text{ for } \varepsilon +r_0 \le x \le x_0-\varepsilon -r_1 \\ 0, \text{ for } x \ge x_0 -\varepsilon + r_1 \end{cases}$,

where $r_0, r_1 >0$ are to be chosen in such a way that the open neighbourhoods $(\varepsilon - r_0, \varepsilon + r_0)$ and $(x_0 - \varepsilon - r_1, x_0-\varepsilon +r_1)$ are non-empty and disjoint.

I am now looking for a way to construct two bump functions, which will make my function smooth (by which I mean $C^{\infty}$) in those intervals. I know that I can construct a bump function by using the function
$ f(x)=\begin{cases}e^{-\frac{1}{x}}&\text{for $x \ge 0$}\\ 0&\text{for $x \le 0$.}\end{cases}$
and then taking $g(x)=\frac{f(x)}{f(x) + f(1-x)}=\begin{cases}1&\text{for $x \ge 1$} \\ 0 &\text{for $x \le 0$ } \end{cases}$.

I know how to change the shape by shifting etc. In particular I am familiar with the construction in Loring W. Tu's book.

But I have two problems:

1. This bump function takes values from $0$ to $1$, but the function that I want should take values between $1$ and $f(\epsilon+r_0)$ respectively $f(x_0-\varepsilon-r_1)$ and $0$. I don't really know how to do this.
2. I am concerned with smoothness. I have an idea of what these bump functions would look like, for instance, in the intervall $(\varepsilon - r_0, \varepsilon + r_0)$ it should look like the constant function $1$ near the left boundary and the constant function $f(\varepsilon+r_0)$ near the right one. How can the transition from the bump function to my linear function $f$ be smooth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should construct a bump function $h_{a,b,\varepsilon}$ with $\mathrm{supp} \, h = [a-\varepsilon,b+\varepsilon]$ and $h(x) =1$ on $[a,b]$, see e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function). You can also construct such functions by using $g$: Define $$h(x) = g\left(\frac{x-(a-\varepsilon)}{\varepsilon}\right) \cdot g \left(\frac{(b+\varepsilon)-x}{\varepsilon} \right).$$
Now you can easily construct your function by taking bump-functions which are supported on disjoint neighbourhoods.

Comment: I see that if I take for instance $h(x)=1-g(\frac{x-(\varepsilon-r_0)}{2r_0})$, that $h(x)=\begin{cases} 1, \text{ for } x \le \varepsilon -r_0, \\0, \text{ for } x \ge \varepsilon+r_0 \end{cases}$. But, what I want is instead that $h(x)=\begin{cases} 1, \text{ for } x \le \varepsilon -r_0, \\ f(\varepsilon+r_0), \text{ for } x \ge \varepsilon+r_0 \end{cases}$. If I just shift my function, this will also change the value where $h$ was 1. How can I change my $h$ in such a way, that this condition is fulfilled?

Comment: Okay, I think I could take instead $1-(f(\varepsilon+r_0)+1) g(\frac{x-(\varepsilon-r_0)}{2r_0})=\begin{cases} 1, \text{ if } x \le \varepsilon-r_0, \\ f(\varepsilon+r_0), \text{ if } x \ge \varepsilon+r_0 \end{cases}$. Will this glue smoothly?

Comment: You can take a function, say $h_1$, with $h_1(x) =1$ for $x \le \varepsilon-r_0$ and $h_1(x)=0$ for $x \ge \varepsilon-r_0/2$. (Just modifiy your function $g$ by rescaling!) Now take $h_2$ as in my answer with $a= \varepsilon+r_0$ and $b=x_0-\varepsilon -r_1$ and $\widetilde{\epsilon} = \min \{r_0,r_1\}$. Then $h_2$ is supported on $[\varepsilon,x_0-\varepsilon]$ and is constant one on $[\varepsilon+r_0,x_0-\varepsilon-r_1]$. Define $\psi = h_1 + h_2 f$. (This choice works!)

Comment: Thank you so much, this really helped me a lot.

Comment: I don't know if this is easy to see, but I have been wondering if it is possible to not have to restrict to $\varepsilon=\min\{r_0, r_1\}$. I feel like this is very restrictive, for instance if I want my function to be 1 in 0, then I wouldn't be able to use this construction.